# Getting random quote from JSON and appending it to div.

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to random quote which is in data.JSON file and append it to some div, but i'm getting error no matter where I put my variables:

My JS file:

```
$(specBut).click(function() {
    var randomQuote;
    $.getJSON('data.json',function(quotes){
        randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    });
    $('.quote').empty().append(randomQuote.quote);
    $('.quote-author').empty().append(randomQuote.author);
});
```

And my data.JSON file:

```
{
  "quotes":
  [{
    "author": "First author",
    "quote": "First"
  }, {
    "author": "Second author",
    "quote": "Second"
  }, {
    "author": "Third author",
    "quote": "Third"
  }, {
    "author": "Last author",
    "quote": "last one"
  }]
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quote' of undefined

And that's how my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="quote-box">
    <div class="head text-center"><h2>Random Quotes!</h2></div>
    <div class="quote"> </div>
    <div class="quote-author"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
       <a class="btn btn-default" id="specBut" href="#" role="button">New RQ</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should use `quotes.quotes`

Comment: What is the value of `quotes` in the callback?

Comment: That's right, it works for me because when I print console.log(quotes); I get "Object {quotes: Array[4]}", so my array is wrapped in object and I need quotes.quotes to make it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is  `$.getJSON('data.json',function(quotes){` here the **quotes** variable passed is the whole JSON doc which has another `quotes` key inside it. Which you can access by **quotes.quotes**. Also as the get method will be asynchronous,you need to perform all the operations inside the callback. So here is how it should be

```
$(specBut).click(function() {
    var randomQuote;
    $.getJSON('data.json',function(quotes){
        randomQuote = quotes.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.quotes.length)];
        $('.quote').empty().append(randomQuote.quote);
        $('.quote-author').empty().append(randomQuote.author);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an HTTP get request (asynchronous). Try this and check console log.

```
$(specBut).click(function() {
var randomQuote;
$.getJSON('data.json',function(data){
    console.log(data);
    randomQuote = data.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.quotes.length)];  
    $('.quote').empty().append(randomQuote.quote);
    $('.quote-author').empty().append(randomQuote.author);
  });  
});
```

Comment: `quotes.length` should be `data.quotes.length`

Answer (score 0):

In this case it looks like `randomQuote` got assigned `undefined` at some point, so it ends up trying to run `undefined.quote` instead of `quote` being accessed on an object.

THere's a problem somewhere with `randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];`

I would log `quotes` to see if it's even defined when you get it.

Answer (score 0):

getJSON method is asynchronouse. Try this:

```
$(specBut).click(function() {
  var randomQuote;
  $.getJSON('data.json',function(quotes){
    randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    $('.quote').empty().append(randomQuote.quote);
    $('.quote-author').empty().append(randomQuote.author);
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must show returned data inside .getJSON callback

```
$(specBut).click(function() {
    var randomQuote;
    $.getJSON('data.json',function(quotes){
        randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
        $('.quote').empty().append(randomQuote.quote);
        $('.quote-author').empty().append(randomQuote.author);
    });
});
```